# Possible to instantiate a PHP instance using a class name property from within a class method (in one line of code)?

Tags: php, constructor, instantiation, classname

I would like to be able to instantiate a class using a class name stored in another class's property, and I want to do this with one line of code, as in the comments in the code below (and it should work on at least one recent version of PHP 5). Is this possible?

```
<?php

class Foo {

  public function doFoo() {

    echo "foo\n";

  }

}

class Bar {

  function __construct($className) {

    $this->className = $className;

  }

  public function doBar() {

    //INSTEAD OF THESE TWO LINES...
    //$className = $this->className;
    //$instance = new $className();

    //I WOULD LIKE THIS (OR SOME OTHER) ONE-LINER TO WORK:
    $instance = $this->className();

    $instance->doFoo();

  }

}

$bar = new Bar('Foo');
$bar->doBar();
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
foo
```

Comment: You just forgot the keyword `new` e.g. `$instance = new $this->className();` (And as you want it this works from PHP version +5.0, see: http://3v4l.org/H3O7X) Your current code would be: `$instance  = Foo();` which is just calling a function Foo

Comment: Also before you ask the next 3 questions which are typos or wrong php version i only can recommend you a quick [google](http://itsfunny.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/How-I-fix-stuff-working-in-IT.jpg) and [SO search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) + a little bit of basic debugging with error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` Also don't forgot the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @Rizier123 You're on the ball today! Good work :D

Comment: @Darren I try my best, and every day a little bit better

Comment: @Rizier123 You're doing great, keep it up!

Comment: OK, I've been getting some great answers today, don't think I'll ask anything more on this topic. Special thanks to @Rizier123 for keeping up all his good work.

Answer (score -1):

There is an obvious typo in the code which is calling a function instead of a constructor, and can be fixed as follows:

```
$instance = new $this->className();
```

That does the trick.

Comment: Questions resulting from typos are off topic and should be deleted, not answered.